# CSS center align div vertically

Tags: css

I want to center align a div veritcally how can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML/CSS</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #box {
            display: flex;
            width: 200px;
            height: 120px;
            background: red;
            margin: auto;
            vertical-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">Hello World!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I referred to this [tutorial](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/) but no gain.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mebutenura/2/edit?html,css,output)

It's all about the container

```
.container{

  display: flex;

  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```